# Is it normal to reply Yes/No to an “A or B” question in English?

Tags: expressions

Below is from Assimil French:

> French version:
>
> "Voulez-vous aller tout de suite à votre hôtel ou voulez-vous passer au bureau d'abord ? "
>
> "Non, je veux déposer mes affaires d'abord."
>
> English version:
>
> "Do you want to go immediately to your hotel or do you want to go (pass by) to the office first?"
>
> "No, I want to drop off my things (affairs) first."

So in French, when facing an "A or B" question, one can reply *No*, to reject "B" and take "A". Is it also so in English? Previouly I always thought that one can't say "Yes/No" to an choice question as it'll confuse people.

Comment: Looking at the Google trans version, it's actually uncertain which stuff he's talking about or where he intends to drop it; he may, in fact be rejecting both suggestions. Without further context we may never know which.

Comment: @Tetsujin I added the English version from the book.

Comment: Doesn't really change what Google came up with; it's still unclear. You could assume he means to go to the hotel. If so, it's an awkward way to say it, it would have been much clearer if he actually stated that. In everyday conversation, though, you'd be amazed [or not] at how many people will answer yes or no to a 2-part either/or question, leaving the questioner having to re-iterate each separately in order to get any sense out of them :/

Comment: I work computer helpline. This is a typical exchange... "Help! My app just crashed" 'Do you really mean crashed or did you just get logged out?' "Yes" 'Which? Did it crash to the desktop or did you see an error message saying you'd been logged out' "No"  & round & round ad-nauseum... You eventually have to remove the choice & extract an answer for each salient part.

Comment: @Tetsujin I took the version from the book as it's well known so I assume it's written by someone does understand French, might be better than Google Translate..

Answer (score 1):

Typically in English, you would state which of the two options you would prefer, or reject both and supply a third. e.g.

> Do you want to go immediately to your hotel or do you want to go to the office first?
>
> Thank you, I would prefer to go to my hotel first.
>
> or
>
> Thank you, but neither. I would like to get a cup of coffee and something to eat first.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you want to go immediately to your hotel

This part of the question is a yes/no question.

> Do you want to go immediately to your hotel or do you want to go (pass by) to the office first?

The full sentence is a "choice question", but here's some thoughts:

- It's rather wordy.  Someone in a hurry and thinking only about the hotel may have really just listened to the first half of it.
- Voice intonation/pauses/nonverbal cues are a very important part of speech and influence interpretation.  The way a speaker could have said this may have communicated that the "or do you want to go to the office first?" is "tacked on".

E.g. if it was said like this

> Do you want to go immediately to your hotel [pause] or [another short pause] do you want to go to the office first?

then what you did was start asking a yes/no question, then turned it into a choice question halfway through the sentence.  It's fair that the listener responded to what he/she thought you were originally trying to say.

You can't say "Yes/no" to a 100% ambiguous choice question - these never start with "Do you want/wish/need to X".  For example:

> Do you want green or red blankets?  (Someone who responds yes/no wasn't listening at all)

Better way to rephrase original question where it can't be answered yes/no is:

> Do you want to go to the hotel or office?

Comment: “It’s fair the listener respond to what he thought you were originally trying to say” — no, actually the replied “no” is refer to choice B